# Frobenius series for the $S_n$-module $k[X]$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, invariant-theory, symmetric-functions

I'm reading Haiman's article titled *Conjectures on the quotient ring by diagonal invariants* (which can be found [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/ftp/diagonal/diagonal.pdf)). In what follows, all vector spaces and algebras are over the field of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$.

First, let $\phi$ the Frobenius characteristic map which assings to each character $\chi$ of $S_n$ a symmetric function $\phi(\chi)$ such that if $\chi_\lambda$ is the character of the irreducible representation of $S_n$ indexed by a partition $\lambda$ of $n$, then $\phi(\chi_\lambda)$ is the  Schur function $s_\lambda$ indexed by the same partition $\lambda$. If $V$ is the representation of $S_n$ whose character is $\chi$, we abuse notation and write $\phi(V)$ instead of $\phi(\chi)$.

Let $A=\bigoplus_{i\geq 0} A_i$ be a graded $S_n$-module. We define the *Frobenius series* of $A$ by
$$
F_A(q) = \sum_{i\geq 0} \phi(A_i) q^{i}.
$$
Similarly, if $A=\bigoplus_{i,j\geq 0} A_{ij}$ is a bigraded $S_n$-bimodule, we define its Frobenius series by

$$
F_A(t,q) = \sum_{i,j\geq 0} \phi(A_{ij}) t^{i}q^{j}.
$$

In Section 1.4 of the cited article, it is mentioned that for $\mathbb{Q}[X]=\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ (with the natural action of $S_n$ permuting the variables), the corresponding Frobenius series is given by
$$
F(q) = \sum_{|\lambda| = n} s_\lambda(1,q,q^2,\dots)s_\lambda(z_1,z_2,\dots) = \left.\prod_{i,j} \frac{1}{1-q^{i}z_ju}\right|_{u^n}
$$
Here the notation $f(u)|_{u^n}$ means to take the coefficient of $u^n$ in the series $f(u)$.

All that is said in the mentioned article, is that this is a well-known computation using MacMahon's master theorem. I'm new in this subject so this is not well-known to me at all, so if you can suggest me some reference where I can find this computation, it would be great!

Finally, in the same section, it is mentioned that for the bigraded ring $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]=\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n]$, where $S_n$ acts by permuting the pairs of variables $(x_i,y_i)$, the corresponding Frobenius series is given by
$$
F(t,q) = \sum_{|\lambda|=n}\sum_{|\mu|=n} s_\lambda(1,t,t^2,\dots)s_\mu(1,q,q^2,\dots)(s_\lambda\ast s_\mu)(z_1,z_2,\dots) = \left.\prod_{i,j,k} \frac{1}{1-t^{i}q^{j}z_k u}\right|_{u^n}
$$
where $s_\lambda\ast s_\mu = \phi(\chi_\lambda\otimes \chi_\mu)$. I don't know where to find this computation either.

Thank you in advance!